# Largest known prime with digit sum $4$?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, big-numbers

According to OEIS , the number $$10^{509546}+3$$ is a (I guess probable) prime with digit sum $4$ in base $10$.

> Is it the largest known such prime ?

> What is the largest known such prime if it must contain four ones (in base $10$) ?

Comment: An example for the latter is $$10^{92386}+111$$

Comment: Why can't a prime have two $1$'s, one $2$  and lots of zeros? For example, $2000000000000010001$ or $10000000000021$. I'm not saying those are prime. I'm saying I don't see why there can't be primes like that.

Comment: @AdamRubinson OP didn't say it must have four 1's. OP asked two questions: which one is the largest? Which one is the largest with four 1's?

Comment: @jjagmath true.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Well , the largest known prime with a two and two ones would be welcome as well , such as $$10^{94983}+21$$ according to OEIS a probable prime.